# Combine two circuit L293D

Tags: h-bridge

Does anyone know whether two circuit L293D can built above themselves that it allows flow high current?

Comment: Sorry, you mean.. _what_ exactly? Please elaborate more, your question is hard to understand.

Comment: I wanted to ask that these circuit can be connected in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what the L293 output stage looks like: -

[image]

I didn't see anything in the product pdf that says that they can be "effectively" paralleled but it's quite possible there was some small print somewhere or I was being stupid. Anyway ***I don't think they can*** (having looked at the circuit). It's the bottom transistors that are probably the main culprit for not allowing parallel connections; one or the other L293 will win the battle to supply most if not all the current through to 0V.

The chip which turns-on down to 0V the most effectively will prevent the darlington pair of the other chip being able to supply anything. Let me know if there's something in the brochure I missed and I'll delete or amend as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, but it is not what I need to know it. My question asked that it can be make connected  two circuits above themselves as shown an picture - (http://www.pixhost.org/show/4654/16550519_vkres1.jpg). I´m sorry I ´m English-speaking amateur.

Comment: @AndrejKozlovský - I've highlighted the words in my answer that you missed reading.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended or not, soldering one of these chips atop another was in fact common practice back in the day.

Today there are many other alternative parts which it would be worth considering instead.